# How to create generic repository function for generic Dao that returns List<T>?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, android-room, android-livedata

Let's say I have BaseDao like the following:

```
@Dao
abstract class BaseHealthRecordDao<T: BaseHealthRecord>(
    private val tableName: String,
    private val roomDatabase: RoomDatabase
) {
    @RawQuery
    protected abstract fun getAllHealthRecordsSync(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): List<T>

    private fun getAllHealthRecordsSync(userId: String): List<T> {
        val query = SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE userId = :$userId")
        return getAllHealthRecordsSync(query)
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    fun getAllHealthRecords(userId: String): LiveData<List<T>> {
        return object : ComputableLiveData<List<T>>() {
            private var observer: InvalidationTracker.Observer? = null
            override fun compute(): List<T> {
                if (observer == null) {
                    observer = object : InvalidationTracker.Observer(tableName) {
                        override fun onInvalidated(tables: Set<String>) = invalidate()
                    }
                    roomDatabase.invalidationTracker.addWeakObserver(observer!!)
                }
                return getAllHealthRecordsSync(userId)
            }
        }.liveData
    }
}
```

And I have several Dao that extend this BaseDao. I want to be able to retrieve all these health records like this:

```
override suspend fun <T : BaseHealthRecord> getAllHealthRecords(
        clazz: Class<T>,
        userId: String
    ): LiveData<List<T>> {
        return when (clazz::class) {
            TemperatureHealthRecord::class -> temperatureHealthRecordDao.getAllHealthRecords(userId)
            PulseOximetryHealthRecord::class -> pulseOximetryHealthRecordDao.getAllHealthRecords(userId)
            BloodSugarHealthRecord::class -> bloodSugarHealthRecordDao.getAllHealthRecords(userId)
            else -> bloodPressureHealthRecordDao.getAllHealthRecords(userId)
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work with returning `LiveData<List<T>>` with getAllHealthRecords because for example, on the line: TemperatureHealthRecord::class -> temperatureHealthRecordDao.getAllHealthRecords(userId) I am getting - required `LiveData<List<T>>` but found `LiveData<List <TemperatureHealthRecord>>`. Is there a way to successfully generify it?

Inspiration for this BaseDao was from this article: https://medium.com/@berryhuang/android-room-generic-dao-27cfc21a4912

But they did not show a repository method that can do what I described.

I tried:

```
override suspend fun <T : BaseHealthRecord> getAllHealthRecords(
        clazz: Class<T>,
        userId: String
    ): LiveData<List<BaseHealthRecord>> {
        return when (clazz::class) {
            TemperatureHealthRecord::class -> temperatureHealthRecordDao.getAllHealthRecords(userId)
            PulseOximetryHealthRecord::class -> pulseOximetryHealthRecordDao.getAllHealthRecords(userId)
            BloodSugarHealthRecord::class -> bloodSugarHealthRecordDao.getAllHealthRecords(userId)
            else -> bloodPressureHealthRecordDao.getAllHealthRecords(userId)
        }
    }
```

Changing the return from `LiveData<List<T>>` to `LiveData<List<BaseHealthRecord>>` and I wasn't getting any values. Any ideas?